# Clang 14 devel can't find "ranges" library

Tags: c++, makefile, clang

I'm using clang-14-devel in Linux, but when I include the "ranges" library I'm getting an error.
The compile flags in my Makefile are like this:

```
-g -O2 -m32 -pipe -std=c++20 -fexceptions -D_THREAD_SAFE -DNDEBUG -fstack-protector-all
```

My error is:

```
fatal error: 'ranges' file not found
#include <ranges>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Not sure, but Clang 13 only claims [partial support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20). Couldn't find any info on Clang 14. Any reason you're using clang-14 right now?

Comment: It's possible that despite Clang supporting C++20 language features, the C++ standard library on your system does not provide a full C++20 conformance.  C++20 is still pretty fresh -- compiler and library support may take a little while to solidify.

Comment: To be doubly sure, are you compiling with the proper libc++? clang does not default to its own library unless the system was built with it (BSD and macOS).